# DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","shaheena","shaheena");error: cannot find symbol DriverManager, Statement st

Tags: java, database-connection

import java.io.*;

import oracle.jdbc.*;

public class JdbcApp6

{

```
       public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception 
      {
       OracleDriver driver=new OracleDriver();
       Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","shaheena","shaheena");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from sss");
    System.out.println("SSNO    SNAME    SBRANCH   SADDR ");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------");
    while(rs.next())
    {
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"   "+rs.getFloat(3)+"  "+rs.getString(4));
    }
    con.close();
}
```

}

Comment: `jdbc:odbc:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl` convert it to `jdbc:odbc:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl`. Append a `/` instead of `:`before `orcl` database name!

Comment: for which symbol are you getting this compile time error?

Comment: Your post title isn't a question it's the error you are receiving, the question might be something like this: Having connection error when using jdbc connection manager

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
```